# setTimeout() continuously calling callback function before its set time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, settimeout

I am trying to set a timer for comment edit feature in my project, for this i used setTimeout() for 15 minutes span. Here is my code (Backbone + Coffee-script): 
In my backbone view i have -

```
initialize : =>  
  @model.bind "change", @render  
  @render() 

render : =>  
  @model.func1()
```

In model -

```
func1: ->  
  if @func2() < 900
    console.log 'in func1'
    @setEditTimeOut()

func2: ->
# this returns total time left (in seconds) for a comment to edit

setEditTimeOut: ->
  console.log 'here in set time out'
  setTimeout (=> @func3()), @func2()*1000

func3 : ->  
  console.log 'in func3'  
  @.trigger 'change'
```

The problem is that `setTimeOut` calling `func3()` repeatedly after some interval, i tried to put console.log to check the calling sequence and i am getting this after some interval :

```
in func3  
in func1  
here in set time out
```

Am i missing something here?. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please use indentation to mark *blocks* of code as code, not back ticks.

Comment: Is your timeout too large by mistake? If it gets bigger than 27 days it will exceed the timeout that setTimeout can handle and get called immediately.

Comment: no, its fine. `setEditTimeOut` is called when time left is < 15 minutes. I also tried to give setTimeout a fixed value say 50000, but no luck, it still calling `func3()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are very likely setting many timeouts, since `setEditTimeOut` gets called any time there is a change in the model within that 15 minute time frame.  You need to make sure you cancel the timeout before you register a new one:

```
setEditTimeOut: ->
  console.log 'here in set time out'
  clearTimeout(@timeoutHandle) if @timeoutHandle
  @timeoutHandle = setTimeout (=> @func3), @func2()*1000
```

Then, (I think, based on your description) you need to make sure you aren't registering more timeouts DURING the timeout handler :

```
func3 : ->  
  @inCallback = true
  console.log 'in func3'  
  @.trigger 'change'
  @inCallback = false

setEditTimeout: ->
  return if @inCallback
  # ...
```

One final note... I noticed that your callback says `(=> @func3)` which is really odd (it shouldn't work at all.  is this a typo?  It should at least read `(=> @func3())`).  Instead, I think you want `setTimeout @func3, @func2()*1000` and then when you define `func3`, uwe the fat arrow: `func3: =>`